# MySQL JOIN causes "ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column" when selecting FROM multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join

Given the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers
(
    CustomerID INT,
    FirstName VARCHAR(32),
    LastName VARCHAR(32)
);

CREATE TABLE Programs
(
    ProgramID INT,
    ProgramName VARCHAR(32)
);

CREATE TABLE Registrations
(
    RegistrationID INT,
    ProgramID INT,
    CustomerID INT
    FirstName VARCHAR(32),
    LastName VARCHAR(32)
);
```

I can't think of any reason why this query should fail:

```
mysql> SELECT *
FROM Registrations R, Programs P
LEFT OUTER JOIN Customers C
ON R.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
WHERE R.ProgramID = P.ProgramID;

ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'C.CustomerID' in 'on clause'
```

But running the query by selecting only the one table `Registrations` causes no errors:

```
mysql> SELECT *
FROM Registrations R
LEFT OUTER JOIN Customers C
ON R.CustomerID = C.CustomerID;

Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

What am I missing?

Before you suggest adding `Customers` to FROM, `CustomerID` is a "loose" association.  For reasons not relevant to this problem, customer data sometimes needs to be decoupled from the registration data with a NULL value for CustomerID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is related  to the use of a mix of  implicit and explicit join
You can't use implict join based on list of comma separated table name and where clause and explicit join  in the same query  ..

```
SELECT *
FROM Registrations R
INNER JOIN  Programs P ON R.ProgramID = P.ProgramID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Customers C ON R.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
```